# 3 tier architecture in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, architecture, runtime

I just finished reading the objective-c developer handbook from apple.  So I pretty much know everything that there is to know about objective-c (hee hee).  I was wondering how do I go about designing a 3-tier application in objective-c.  The 3-tiers being a front-end application in Cocoa, a middle-tier in pure objective-c and a back-end (data access also in objective-c and mysql db).

I'm not really interested in discussing why I'd need a 3-tier architecture, I'd like to narrow the discussion to the 'how'.

For example, can I have 3 separate x-code projects one for each tier?  If so how would I link the projects together.  In java, I can export each tier as a jar file and form the proper associations.

Thanks!

Comment: This belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: well, seems you don't know **everything** about Objective-C after all..

Comment: jeez - that was clearly intended as a joke...

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out how to do this...use a static library for the middle and back-end tier use a Cocoa app for the front end.